# Flutter: RefreshIndicator reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listitem on RefreshIndicator and each of the items have a navigator.pushNamed which redirect a new page.
I need reload RefreshIndicator when i run Navigator.pop(context) in the new page.

```
//Home
RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: _con.refreshHome,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    width: size.width * 0.8,
                    child: OrdenWidget(
                      orden: currentData[index],
                      mostrarComenzar: true,
                      onTap: currentData[index].aceptada ==
                              true
                          ? () {
                               Navigator.PushNamed(
                                context,
                                "/New Page",
                                arguments: currentData[index],
                              ).then((_) {
                                _con.refreshHome();
                              });
                            }
                          : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  itemCount: currentData.length,
                ),
              ),
```

```
//Second Screen

TextButton(onPressed:(){ Navigator.pop(context);}, child: const Text("Go Back"),),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `Navigator.push`

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => NewPage()),
).then((_){
  _con.refreshHome();
});
```